# Listening for a JS event implemented via GTM and tracking it in GA4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

My page integrates an app which provides a JS SDK.

This SDK allows me to listen for events and do callbacks like this one:

```
function doThis() {
    // tell GA4 the event happened
}

$myApp.push(["on", "event:triggered", doThis]);
```

I've implemented GTM on my website following the updated instructions, and I am able to push the above code onto my page by using this setup:
**Trigger:** On Window loaded
**Tag:** Custom HTML (with the above code)

I've also been able to implement GA4 through GTM by creating a Tag for the GA4 Configuration with my Measurement ID (on Window Loaded as well).

However, I do not understand how the above event (which I've implemented through GTM) can be tracked in GA4.
I would like to be able to see this event the same way I am able to view page views for instance.

I imagine this is probably basic, but I've not been able to figure it out despite my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. This is basic indeed. All you need in your callback is to push an event to the dataLayer. Something like:

```
window.dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({event: "name-it-meaningfully"});
```

Then in GTM, you make a trigger like so:

[image]

That's it. This trigger will be triggered by your callback. You can add more fields to that object and they will be available on the DL Event trigger.

Read more on DL [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer).

Comment: I believe this is working, I've added the GA4 Tag to bind that trigger and I'm able to see it (just in the Realtime GA4 for now, but it's there). 
Thanks a lot! 
I will do some more tests to try to add more objects as you mentioned. 
thanks again for explaining it

Comment: yeah, usually we don't deploy listeners through GTM since they look ugly in the DOM and    it goes against best practices. Usually front-end hosts (and maintains!) the callbacks and communicates with us through the dataLayer only. But we certainly can host them.

Comment: thanks for precising it, i will use those parsimoniously. 
I was able to add more objects as well, so thanks again for the information you've shared!